# Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, polymorphic-associations

I get the error
Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :messageable_fromuser

```
online = Message.all.joins(:messageable_fromuser)
```

I tried

```
online = Message.all.includes(:messageable_fromuser)
```

But it doesn't include the joined table in the result. I see two queries in my log when using includes. I don't know why people recommend using includes to eager load. How is two queries going to join anything?

Comment: At first it would be quite helpful, if you would post your model classes that are involved. Further on the second query you see in your logs should end with something like `IN (1, 10)` (the actual numbers will differ). This part of the query fills the role of joining both tables. [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) has a simple example of the IN operator.

Answer (score 7):

With polymorphic you need to manually set the joins.

```
Message.joins("JOIN polymorphic_association.owner_id = messages.id AND polymorphic_association.owner_type = 'User'")
```

If you want to dynamically get the relationship you could do:

```
owner_type = 'User' # or whatever other models can have the association
Message.joins("JOIN polymorphic_association.owner_id = messages.id AND polymorphic_association.owner_type = ?", owner_type)
```

Comment: This JOIN statements won't work this way because they are not complete.

Comment: Won't this only filter the associations? I am guessing we'll also need to preload the messageable_fromuser, if it's to be accessed somewhere that is

Answer (score 7):

Using `preload` should solve the error:

```
online = Message.preload(:messageable_fromuser)
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time is passed but I also have faced this issue and for me using `preloading` is helped.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L161

Comment: An example would have been nice how to use it in the case of the thread openers question.